# Manually starting MIL(Malfunction Indicactor Light)

Tags: cel, obd-ii, mil, dtc

I want to know how can i manually start my Malfunction Engine Light (Check Engine Light) ? i actually want to generate a DTC so that i can see it on a OBD Scanner. I know even altering or removing/cutting any sensor will probably generate a DTC but i want a solution which is easy, doesnt require any cutting and DTC is generated fast.

Comment: Sensors will all have detachable plugs to their pigtails. No cutting is required to disconnect a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can think of is to remove the gas cap and start the engine. You should quickly see a MIL. The scan tool should report something like Evap emission fault large leak.

Comment: Will the evap vacuum be tested immediately upon starting? My understanding is that it requires a drive cycle.

Comment: it depends on how full the tank is, the test is more likely to occur if the tank is not near empty or just topped off. The advantage of using the gas cap is that it is designed to be removed thus unlikely to be accidently damaged. Electrical connectors may be damaged if repeatedly disconnected.

Comment: are you talking about the fuel cap, coz i have a petrol version. and is there any other which will work fast like this one?  Also Does the handbrake can generate any DTC?

Answer (score 1):

The gas or petrol cap is a good idea. Removing the coil pack(s), on cylinder 1, is another one.

Sometimes you can easily find an electrical connector - say the O2 sensor - and disconnect it. This, of course, depends on what connectors are easily reachable. On a Hyundai Coupe, the O2 sensor is easily accessible.